# Can someone be tracked in real time 24/7?

Tags: tracking

I'm in a situation where I know the person behind this is doing it, but not sure how.

It's been over a year and people seem to show up to places that I go to, places that I've told privately and places that I've gone out on a whim.

I've heard weird things from friends such as, repeating things that I've said on my landline phone in a private conversation and also mentioning places that I've gone to time and time again (i.e. gym, places that I frequent to eat, etc).

These are people that do not live in the same state as me either.

Also, I've been accused of having a social media account with tons of followers, but not one person will tell me where and why they are saying this. Almost as if it should be a secret.

The person behind this is a former business partner and a sociopathic liar. It seems as though everyone around me is convinced that I'm the one posting/writing things and I'm deemed as crazy when I deny it.

Can a car be traced 24/7 in real time and can landlines /cell phones be hacked easily? This person has also stolen my social security card and id as well.

Comment: It's the age of IoT, Botnets, Govt. leaked Hacking tools. So, to your questions, I would simply say **Yes**.

Comment: would it feasible to say that this person is tracking me somehow through my vehicle and has hacked my landline? i've had family members accuse me of doing all this

Comment: Yes, it is feasible to say that. As for the Car Hacking thing, Read [this article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/these-are-the-most-interesting-ways-to-hack-internet-connected-vehicles/) and If interested to get your hands on this [freecodecamp good read](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/hacking-cars-a-guide-tutorial-on-how-to-hack-a-car-5eafcfbbb7ec).

Comment: hm, im just trying to figure out how he would be tracking me 24/7 either real time or not, but eventually figure out where i frequent. And these aren't coincidences either, normally if you see someone you know in a random place, you say hi or acknowledge one another, but all it seems like is that they're just trying to confirm that I'm there.

Comment: While I agree that the answer is that somebody can be tracked 24/7 it is unknown if tracking is actually done in this case and how (there are tons of ways). Given that this is not a discussion site but a clear question+answer site the primary question (can it be done) is answered (yes) and a not directly asked but kind of inherent question of how this is done in the specific case cannot be answered. Insofar I propose to close the question as too broad since it can not really be answered with the given information and every attempt to answer it would just result in wild speculations.

Comment: If you know the person and they've stolen your social security card/number and id, why haven't you gone to the police?

Comment: Yes, everything you say is possible.